# Stop Manipulation JS timer Client side

Tags: javascript, security, browser, timer, client-server

I am developing an quiz application which requires to calculate the exact time taken by user to give an answer for an question.

I can not implement timer for that on server side because of **latency** issues which may arise because for different users and their different network/service provider.

If I implement timer at client side , there are highly chances that **user can edit and manipulate the time.**

**is there a way to create a secure timer at client side that user can not manipulate.**

Comment: do you need to show the timer to the users?

Comment: i think you have more than 1 timer. let's say 3 timers that start at the same time and when it get sent to the server, you take those 3 timers and validate them, check if they are similar, if one is wrong then you'll know that one has been modify. of course you need to encrypt them and assign them to some random characters variable before send them to the server.

Comment: Yes I am required to show timer to user

Comment: no I don't have multiple timers. I have only one timer to calculate the time.

Comment: my apology. i meant you *should* have more than 1 timer.

Comment: basically, show a fake timer to the users and have multiple real and hidden timer for the server. so user can modify that fake timer all they want.

Comment: you are right , what if user Change both timer?

Answer (score 0):

you can manage this storing a timestamp at the backend side when the user starts the quiz, then, with this timestamp, you can implement a client side timer, once the user finishes the quiz, the client sends an event to the backend and a "finish" timestamp is generated, so you can know how much time does the user took to answer the questionnaire by subtracting both timestamps.

[image]

Comment: about the finish request - if that quiz finish request got late just because of network traffic/latency then again it will difficult to get the exact time for the quiz end.

Comment: If the problem is the latency, just store that finished_at timestamp somewhere at client side like localStorage, and you can have a task with a javascript Web Worker wich is listening for the time to be sent. that worker performes the server request.

Comment: If I will add such timestamp at client side there are high chances user can manipulate it

Comment: just encrypt it